# How to enable wpe webkit support for touchscreen

Tags: webkit, yocto, wpe

I was able to successfully build a yocto (warrior) image using also meta-webkit (https://github.com/Igalia/meta-webkit)
The device on which I install the image is an imx6 board with a touchscreen (x11 and wayland are disabled)

Using cog I am able to open a java based application running on localhost.

The issue I have is that although I am able to see the webpage, the touchscreen events are not forwarded to the application.

Is there any configuration that must be enabled in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting a known issue with lost touch events. See [Bug 214141](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214141): “*[WPE] lost touch events, wrong mousedown events*” in WebKit's bugzilla.

There are some instructions there to reproduce the issue so you can verify if the issue is the same.